# Как получить гео данние в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Помогите получить гео-данные для моего погодного приложения, использовал модуль но он не точно определяет, читал что можно на стороне клиента но не мог найти решение, помогите пожалуйста как можно и на стороне сервера и на стороне клиента получить гео-данные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Про какие «гео данние» речь? Ничего не понятно

Comment: @andreymal - геолокация, долгота и широта